# Concat a column using fputcsv

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

I have a program where the user can download the csv file of all the queried values from the database. However in one of my columns, I need to concat the words ""Serial Number - " and my m.sr_no value.  How can I possibly do it?

```js
if(isset($_POST["Export"])){
   
      header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Sample.csv');  
      $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  
      fputcsv($output, array('SR_NO', 'MODEL', 'EWR_NO',  'BUILD_NAME',  'SA_MB', 'DESTINATION', 'REQUESTOR', 'PURPOSE', 'WAFERNUM', 
  'CELL', 'QTY', 'MATERIAL_FORM', 'SAMPLE_CRITERIA', 'REQUEST_DATE', 'SORTING_ECD', 'HGA_ECD', 'STATUS', 'UPDATED_BY', 'REMARKS'));  
     $query = "SELECT m.sr_no, a.model, m.ewr_no, m.build_name, m.sa_mb, a.destination, m.requestor, m.purpose, m.wafernum, 
    m.cell, m.qty, a.material_form, a.criteria, m.request_date, m.sorting_ecd, m.hga_ecd, m.status, m.updated_by, m.remarks, m.id_sorting, a.id_optionlist
    FROM sorting  m
    INNER JOIN dynamic_optionlist a ON m.id_sorting = a.id_optionlist 
    WHERE STATUS in ('Open','On-Going','On-Queue','Done')";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
      {  
           fputcsv($output, $row);  
      }  
      fclose($output);  
 }
```

Comment: Which keys do you have to concat it to?

Comment: m.sr_no should output as "Serial Number - *m.sr_no value*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:

replace your `while` loop with the following :

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
 {  
   $row['m.sr_no'] = "Serial Number-".$row['m.sr_no'];
   fputcsv($output, $row);  
 }
```

Solution 2:

update your query as `nick` mentioned:

```
CONCAT('Serial Number - ', m.sr_no) AS sr_no,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the concat in your query using MySQL's [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
$query = "SELECT CONCAT('Serial Number - ', m.sr_no) AS sr_no, ...";
```